# COBOL issue (Compiling and executing)

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I am receiving an error from the compiler when compiling my COBOL program.  Included below is the compiler output followed by by source code.

The error is:

> ==000061==> IGYPS2143-S Expected a record-name, but found "BLANK-LINE".  The statement was discarded.

Compiler output:

```
                   J E S 2  J O B  L O G  --  S Y S T E M  8 5 6 1  --  N O D E  S V S C J E S 2
 

  LineID  PL SL  ----+-*A-1-B--+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7-|--+----8 Map and Cross Reference
  000001                identification division.
  000002                program-id. A1CLIST.
  000003                date-written. 1/19/2024.
  000004                author. Francisco Gonzalez Moreno.
  000005               *Description: COBOL program to create a contact list.
  000006               *
  000007                environment division.
  000008                configuration section.
  000009               *
  000010                input-output section.
  000011                file-control.
  000012               *
  000013                    select output-file                                                    19
  000014                        assign to OUTFILE
  000015                        organization is sequential.
  000016               *
  000017                data division.
  000018                file section.
  000019                FD OUTPUT-FILE
  000020                    recording mode is F
  000021                    data record is OUTPUT-LINE                                            *
  000022                    record contains 81 characters.
  000023               *
  000024               * Outputs
  000025                01 OUTPUT-LINE                           PIC X(81).
  000026               *
  000027                working-storage section.
  000028               *
  000029               *> Heading
  000030                01 HEADING-VARIABLE.
  000031                    05 HEADING-TEXT                      PIC X(12)
  000032                        VALUE "Contact List".
  000033                             *>----+----+--
  000034                    05 FILLER                            PIC X(10)
  000035                        VALUE SPACES. *> spaces within sentence                           IMP
  000036               *Variables
  000037                01 CONTACT-VARIABLE.
  000038                    05 NAME                              PIC X(25).
  000039                    05 FILLER                            PIC X(5)
  000040                         VALUE SPACES. *> spaces within sentence                          IMP
  000041                    05 EMAIL                             PIC X(34).
  000042                    05 FILLER                            PIC X(5)
  000043                        VALUE SPACES. *> spaces within sentence                           IMP
  000044                    05 PHONE-NUMBER                      PIC X(12).
  000045               * formating
  000046                01 BLANK-LINE                           PIC X(40)
  000047                    VALUE SPACES. *> spaces within sentence                               IMP
  000048
  000049               * main code
  000050                procedure division.
  000051                000-main.
  000052                    *> Open the output file
  000053                    OPEN OUTPUT OUTPUT-FILE.                                              19
  000054
  000055               *
  000056               * Header
  000057               *
PP 5655-EC6 IBM Enterprise COBOL for z/OS  6.3.0 P230918       A1CLIST   Date 01/20/2024  Time 15:05:55   Page     4
  LineID  PL SL  ----+-*A-1-B--+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7-|--+----8 Map and Cross Reference
  000058                         MOVE HEADING-TEXT TO OUTPUT-LINE.                                31 25
  000059                             *> Displaying the header
  000060                             WRITE OUTPUT-LINE.                                           25
  000061                             WRITE BLANK-LINE.                                            46
 
==000061==> IGYPS2143-S Expected a record-name, but found "BLANK-LINE".  The statement was
                        discarded.
 
  000062               *
  000063               * 1st person
  000064               *
  000065                         *> Entering information for 1st person
  000066                         MOVE "Francisco Gonzalez Moreno"         TO NAME.                38
  000067                             *>----+----0----+----0----+
  000068                         MOVE "francisco.gonzalezmoreno@dcmail.ca" TO EMAIL.              41
  000069                             *>----+----0----+----0----+----0----
  000070                         MOVE "289-943-3120"                    TO PHONE-NUMBER.          44
  000071                             *>----+----0--
  000072               *
  000073                         *> Moving all inputs to OUTPUT-LINE
  000074                         MOVE NAME         TO OUTPUT-LINE.                                38 25
  000075                         MOVE EMAIL        TO OUTPUT-LINE.                                41 25
  000076                         MOVE PHONE-NUMBER TO OUTPUT-LINE.                                44 25
  000077                             *> and ensuring visibility
  000078                             *> Displaying 1st contact information
  000079                             WRITE OUTPUT-LINE.                                           25
  000080                             WRITE BLANK-LINE.                                            46
 
==000080==> IGYPS2143-S Expected a record-name, but found "BLANK-LINE".  The statement was
                        discarded.
 
  000081               *
  000082               * 2nd person
  000083               *
  000084                         *> Entering information for 2nd person
  000085                         MOVE "Steven Brelik"           TO NAME.                          38
  000086                             *>----+----0
  000087                         MOVE "steven.brelik@dcmail.ca" TO EMAIL.                         41
  000088                             *>----+----0----+----0---
  000089                         MOVE "987-654-3210"            TO PHONE-NUMBER.                  44
  000090                             *>----+----0--
  000091               *
  000092                         *> Moving all inputs to OUTPUT-LINE
  000093                         MOVE NAME         TO OUTPUT-LINE.                                38 25
  000094                         MOVE EMAIL        TO OUTPUT-LINE.                                41 25
  000095                         MOVE PHONE-NUMBER TO OUTPUT-LINE.                                44 25
  000096                             *> Displaying 2nd contact information
  000097                             *> and ensuring visibility
  000098                             WRITE OUTPUT-LINE.                                           25
  000099                             WRITE BLANK-LINE.                                            46
 
==000099==> IGYPS2143-S Expected a record-name, but found "BLANK-LINE".  The statement was
                        discarded.
 
  000100               *
  000101               * 3rd person
  000102               *
PP 5655-EC6 IBM Enterprise COBOL for z/OS  6.3.0 P230918       A1CLIST   Date 01/20/2024  Time 15:05:55   Page     5
  LineID  PL SL  ----+-*A-1-B--+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7-|--+----8 Map and Cross Reference
  000103                         *> Entering information for 3rd person
  000104                         MOVE "Robbie McDonald" TO NAME.                                  38
  000105                             *>----+----0----+
  000106                         MOVE "robbie.mcdonald@dcmail.ca" TO EMAIL.                       41
  000107                             *>----+----0----+----0----+
  000108                         MOVE "555-123-4567" TO PHONE-NUMBER.                             44
  000109                             *>----+----0--
  000110               *
  000111                          *> Moving all inputs to OUTPUT-LINE
  000112                         MOVE NAME         TO OUTPUT-LINE.                                38 25
  000113                         MOVE EMAIL        TO OUTPUT-LINE.                                41 25
  000114                         MOVE PHONE-NUMBER TO OUTPUT-LINE.                                44 25
  000115                             *> Displaying 3rd contact information
  000116                             *> and ensuring visibility
  000117                             WRITE OUTPUT-LINE.                                           25
  000118
  000119               *
  000120                    *> Close the output file
  000121                    CLOSE OUTPUT-FILE.                                                    19
  000122                    goback.
  000123               *
  000124                end program A1CLIST.                                                      2
  000125
```

## MY CODE

```
       identification division.
       program-id. A1CLIST.
       date-written. 1/19/2024.
       author. Francisco Gonzalez Moreno.
      *Description: COBOL program to create a contact list.
      *
       environment division.
       configuration section.
      *
       input-output section.
       file-control.
      *
           select output-file
               assign to OUTFILE
               organization is sequential.
      *
       data division.
       file section.
       FD OUTPUT-FILE
           recording mode is F
           data record is OUTPUT-LINE
           record contains 81 characters.
      *
      * Outputs
       01 OUTPUT-LINE                           PIC X(81).
      *
       working-storage section.
      *
      *> Heading
       01 HEADING-VARIABLE.
           05 HEADING-TEXT                      PIC X(12)
               VALUE "Contact List".
                    *>----+----+--
           05 FILLER                            PIC X(10)
               VALUE SPACES. *> spaces within sentence
      *Variables
       01 CONTACT-VARIABLE.
           05 NAME                              PIC X(25).
           05 FILLER                            PIC X(5)
                VALUE SPACES. *> spaces within sentence
           05 EMAIL                             PIC X(34).
           05 FILLER                            PIC X(5)
               VALUE SPACES. *> spaces within sentence
           05 PHONE-NUMBER                      PIC X(12).
      * formating
       01 BLANK-LINE                           PIC X(40)
           VALUE SPACES. *> spaces within sentence

      * main code
       procedure division.
       000-main.
           *> Open the output file
           OPEN OUTPUT OUTPUT-FILE.

      *
      * Header
      *
                MOVE HEADING-TEXT TO OUTPUT-LINE.
                    *> Displaying the header
                    WRITE OUTPUT-LINE.
                    WRITE BLANK-LINE.
      *
      * 1st person
      *
                *> Entering information for 1st person
                MOVE "Francisco Gonzalez Moreno"         TO NAME.
                    *>----+----0----+----0----+
                MOVE "francisco.gonzalezmoreno@dcmail.ca" TO EMAIL.
                    *>----+----0----+----0----+----0----
                MOVE "289-943-3120"                    TO PHONE-NUMBER.
                    *>----+----0--
      *
                *> Moving all inputs to OUTPUT-LINE
                MOVE NAME         TO OUTPUT-LINE.
                MOVE EMAIL        TO OUTPUT-LINE.
                MOVE PHONE-NUMBER TO OUTPUT-LINE.
                    *> and ensuring visibility
                    *> Displaying 1st contact information
                    WRITE OUTPUT-LINE.
                    WRITE BLANK-LINE.
      *
      * 2nd person
      *
                *> Entering information for 2nd person
                MOVE "Steven Brelik"           TO NAME.
                    *>----+----0
                MOVE "steven.brelik@dcmail.ca" TO EMAIL.
                    *>----+----0----+----0---
                MOVE "987-654-3210"            TO PHONE-NUMBER.
                    *>----+----0--
      *
                *> Moving all inputs to OUTPUT-LINE
                MOVE NAME         TO OUTPUT-LINE.
                MOVE EMAIL        TO OUTPUT-LINE.
                MOVE PHONE-NUMBER TO OUTPUT-LINE.
                    *> Displaying 2nd contact information
                    *> and ensuring visibility
                    WRITE OUTPUT-LINE.
                    WRITE BLANK-LINE.
      *
      * 3rd person
      *
                *> Entering information for 3rd person
                MOVE "Robbie McDonald" TO NAME.
                    *>----+----0----+
                MOVE "robbie.mcdonald@dcmail.ca" TO EMAIL.
                    *>----+----0----+----0----+
                MOVE "555-123-4567" TO PHONE-NUMBER.
                    *>----+----0--
      *
                 *> Moving all inputs to OUTPUT-LINE
                MOVE NAME         TO OUTPUT-LINE.
                MOVE EMAIL        TO OUTPUT-LINE.
                MOVE PHONE-NUMBER TO OUTPUT-LINE.
                    *> Displaying 3rd contact information
                    *> and ensuring visibility
                    WRITE OUTPUT-LINE.

      *
           *> Close the output file
           CLOSE OUTPUT-FILE.
           goback.
      *
       end program A1CLIST.
```

hoping to get a answer and this is my first time using stack overflow so idk what to expect

Comment: What do [tag:python] and [tag:java] have to do with it? And what is your question?

Comment: As currently stated it is unclear what you wanted to ask. From the question it _looks_ like you can just drop the source (as it is included in the compiler) and instead say "there is no blank line printed" (of course - the compiler already told you so); you likely wanted something like `WRITE OUTPUT-LINE FROM BLANK-LINE` at this place

Comment: @SimonSobisch Nothing is printed. The code doesn’t compile.

Comment: @PureVideo - please find the answer below and mark it as "works for you", possibly with having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/tour which will provide you with your first badge, too.

Comment: @user207421 that's not a question ;-)

Comment: @SimonSobisch From the question it looks like the compiler error `IGYPS2143-S Expected a record-name, but found "BLANK-LINE"`, and it certainly doesn't look anything like 'there is no blank line printed'. Read it.

Comment: I've referenced this in my comment, too - but don't know if there's an option to create executable code with severe error level on IBM (and if this is activated) or not.

Answer (score 5):

`BLANK-LINE` is not a record-name associated with a file. However, `OUTPUT-LINE` is. Use the following:

```
WRITE OUTPUT-LINE FROM BLANK-LINE.
```

Comment: Better still, `WRITE OUTPUT-LINE FROM HEADING TEXT BEFORE ADVANCING 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Change from:

```
        *> Moving all inputs to OUTPUT-LINE
        MOVE NAME         TO OUTPUT-LINE.
        MOVE EMAIL        TO OUTPUT-LINE.
        MOVE PHONE-NUMBER TO OUTPUT-LINE.
```

Change to:

```
        *> Moving all inputs to OUTPUT-LINE
        MOVE CONTACT-VARIABE TO OUTPUT-LINE.
```

`NAME`, `EMAIL`, and `PHONE-NUMBER` are defined under `CONTACT-VARIABE`.

Comment: The question is about a compilation error, and you haven't answered it.

Comment: Thanks @hroder for registering just to add the answer. The question was not 100% clear and you're right that this is an _additional_ issue next to the compile error (which is likely what the question is _mostly_ about).
In any case: please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/tour which will provide you with more details how this site works (as well as providing you with the first badge :-)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).